# How to show alert message with specific data from database

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Actually I want to make an alert message with specific data inside it, for example ***'product 1 has reached its level'***.
I cannot do it so I tried another way to show the alert message but not with specific pid inside it.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=aaaVAIO;InitialCatalog=System;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand abc = new SqlCommand("select pid, case when (Pamount <= SafetyStock) then 'has reached its limit!' end as Alert from Product ", connection);

try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = abc.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(rdr["alert"].ToString());
            foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Text.Equals("Limit stock has been reached"))
                {
                    ClientScriptManager def= Page.ClientScript;
                      {
                        string strconfirm = "<script>if(window.confirm('Limit Stock has been reached!')){window.location.href='/Inventory system/Manager/Updateproductdetails.aspx'}</script>";
                        def.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
                      }

                }
            }
         }

         rdr.Close();
     }
```

At code above, I store the `sqlcommand` output in `list box` then the alert message will show the alert message based on the list content. If there is limit stock has been reached message in the listbox then the alert message will come out.

Actually I want to make it more specific where it shows the specific pid that reached its limit. For example, the alert message will show message ***'Product 1 has reached its limit'***.

Please suggest me solution for this problem.
Should I store the value in `gridview` first? Or any other way to do it?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: 1: go to amazon. 2: buy on of the "learning some prgramming in 21 days" books, 3: implement what you learned. You should know what you want - not ask us (as in: the UI flow is not a programming decision but one that is part of your UI concept..... and if you ahve none start thinking, because this is the difference between good and crpa software - usability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your sql query to show the items just with the amount <= to the safetyStock:

```
SqlCommand abc = new SqlCommand("select pid from Product where Pamount <= SafetyStock", connection);
```

Then your loop change it for something like this:

```
 while (rdr.Read())
            {
                ClientScriptManager def = Page.ClientScript;
                {
                    string strconfirm = "<script>if(window.confirm('Product " + rdr["pid"] + " has reached its limit')){window.location.href='/Inventory system/Manager/Updateproductdetails.aspx'}</script>";
                    def.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
                }

            }
```